# Break down text from text file into commands with Tokenizer - homework

Tags: java

I have a project due for school that draws shapes and makes them move. The program(what I thought was the hard part) works fine but the teacher is going to test it by using a text file. I am having a hard time breaking the commands she will use down. I am using bufferreader to read the file then I loop through the tokens but thats where i get confused. How would I go about breaking the token into strings and integers and trigger the proper methods? Any constructive guidance would be appreciated.

Here's my code to read the file

```
   static void getTokens() throws Exception {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the file name ---> ");
        fileName = input.next();

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String element = inFile.readLine();

       // tokenize string with " " as the delimiter
       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(element, " ");

       // loop through tokens
       while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
           txtAnalysis(tokenizer.nextToken());

        }
       //close file
       inFile.close();
}
```

Here is an example of the text the teacher will use.

```
    start picture A
    circle 50 100 20
    coloredcircle 0 100 20 green
    end picture
    draw picture A blue 10 10
    dance picture A 30 30 
    erase
    start picture B
    rectangle 0 100 20 40
    rectangle 100 100 40 20
    rectangle 200 100 40 20
    Sshape 55 55 55 55 55 yellow Elf
    Sshape 55 25 35 45 65 red Ogre
    end picture
    draw picture B yellow 10 10
    erase
    draw picture A blue 10 10
```

Comment: i dont think its a good idea to process every single token alone, i would suggest you process the whole line at once, since you cant draw a shape without coordinates

Comment: You should loop over the file lines, rather than on the tokens of each line.

Comment: ok that's no problem but I still am not sure how to distinguish integers and String from one another and A or the string at the end of the first line has to be the identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
public void txtAnalysis(String line){
    if(line.startsWith("start picture")){
       String label = line.split(" ")[2];
       currentPicture = new Picture(label);
    }
    if(line.startsWith("end picture")){
       save(currentPicture);//or pictures.put(currentPicture.getLabel(), currentPicture);
       currentPicture = null;
    }
    if(line.startsWith("circle")){
       String[] parts = line.split(" ");
       currentPicture.addShape(new Cirlce(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Integer.parseInt(parts[2]), Integer.parseInt(parts[3])));
    }
    if(line.startsWith("draw picture")){
       String[] parts = line.split(" ");
       Picture pic = pictures.get(parts[2]);
       pic.draw(parts[3], Integer.parseInt(parts[4]), Integer.parseInt(parts[5]));
    }
    ...
}
```

are you looking for something like this?

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than what I was thinking. I was way over complicating it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will use some kind of Strategy or Factory patterns.

```
// loop through tokens
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    DrawerFactory factory = 
         AbstractProgramFactory.getFactory(tokenizer.nextToken());
    factory.process(tokenizer);
}
```

Then your AbstractProgramFactory.getFactory will have the if/else behaviour and will return an implementation that know how to execute any command.

```
interface DrawerFactory{
    void process(final Tokenizer tokenizer);
}
```

Comment: It's homework... It would't really look like he thought this by himself, would it?

Comment: Well, it will depend on how long he is in his studies, when I was on third year I already knew about design patterns

Comment: Thanks but they are right I'm in programming 2 and recently realized I'm not going to learn programing from power points.

Comment: The approach will probably not work, due to loss of context. It looks like "start picture" / "end picture" form like brackets, with subobjects.

Comment: @Ingo it is already not choosen, so dont care about it, you will loose context if you dont share it, it is an approach for him to use, not a this is how is EXACTLY done :P